# Move cursor via Xpath

Tags: html, xpath, ace-editor

Within the Ace editor HTML panel is it possible to move the cursor if I know the Xpath of the dom element?
For instance if I have this path

```
/html/body/nav/ul/li[2]
```

I would love to be able to move the cursor to

```
<html>
 <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
               <li>Alpha</li>
               *here*<li>Beta</li>
               <li>Gama</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess one option is to write a regex based on opening tags but maybe there was a cleaner way. Haven't been able to see from the API if it's possible.,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was over thinking the problem. I reinterpreted the path

```
/html/body/nav/ul/li[2]
```

to

```
/html/body/nav/ul/li/li
```

Split those and then had the Ace editor do a sequential find from the beginning. So find "<html" and then "<body" and then "<nav" etc.